# How to trace SMB connection to what process initiated the connection?

Tags: windows, forensics, smb

I have a situation where I see a bunch of SMB connections initiated from a client to a server every night and it triggers an SMB brute-force alert on my Firewall.

I installed Sysmon on the server to monitor what initiates the connection, but the PID is 4 which is the System process in Windows.

I'm looking for a way to monitor what has initiated this SMB connection. Maybe it's a logon script? Or some different job?

How can I identify which process / job requested this SMB connection?

Edit:
To clarify, the event id is 3 for network connection and on this event id the initiating PID is 4

Answer (score 1):

With information such as the destination address, identifying an object handle to `\Device\Mup` and trace back to a process would help in this situation. This can be done with [Handle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) or Volatility `handles` command in case there is a memory dump file.

```
explorer.exe pid: 2904 UNNAMED\Administrator
   10: File  (RW-)   C:\Windows\System32
   8C: File  (R-D)   C:\Windows\en-US\explorer.exe.mui
  17C: Section       \Windows\Theme1983439688
 .......
 16F0: File  (RWD)   \Device\Mup\192.168.1.2\C$
 1754: File  (R-D)   C:\Windows\System32\en-US\hcproviders.dll.mui
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally if trying to figure out what's making the connection there would be some monitoring (eg. procmon / packet capture on the client side. The server PID will always be the same since that's the server process and it's not initiating the connection, simply serving a response.

If it's not possible to monitor the client and the monitoring must be done on the server then there are a few methods that could be employed:

- Network packet capture, which would show what kind of SMB traffic was hitting which ports
- File system auditing, which would show if there were files being accessed at the same time
- Process monitoring, which will show everything the system is doing - very verbose

Since it's the firewall triggering the alert it's likely network traffic, so a packet capture would be a good place to start. That might lead you to do something else in terms of monitoring.

Note also that a personal firewall / IDS might also help. If that's what is meant by "firewall" above then see if there are some verbose logs in there to tell what's going on.